# Have server code continue to send data back to browser while processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my ASP.NET app I would like to have the browser page call a method on the server. The method needs to carry out a lengthy process and I would like it to periodically send data back to the client with the connection that was established when the client connected to the server. However, I don't want the connection to close until the server has completed its process. Is this possible?

It would be nice to do this with jQuery. I'm running ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could fire off one ajax request which starts the lengthy process, then in that lengthy process set a session value with the data you want to send back.

After firing off the first ajax request, you could then send another request every 10 seconds or so that simply returns the value of the session you set earlier.

Something like this for the jquery side:

```
var completed = false;

$.ajax({
  url: '/lengthyprocess',
  success: function () {
    completed = true;
  }
});


function checkStatus() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/lengthyprocessstatus',
    success: function (response) {
      $('#status').html(response);
      if (!completed) {
        setTimeout(checkStatus, 10000);
      }
    }
  });
}

checkStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use web sockets

var connection = new WebSocket('ws://serverip');

```
// Log messages from the server
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
if(e.data == "predefined value"){
  connection.close();
}else{
  console.log('Receieved from Server: ' + e.data);
}
};
```